# Best way to solve sum of an array with .each

Tags: arrays, ruby, algorithm

Below is some code I submitted for a array sum algorithm.  In this case I had to use .each but I feel like there is a better way to do this...

```
numbers = [5, 17, 2, 899, 101, 4, 66, 123, 98]
sum = 0
index = 0
numbers.each do |number|
  sum = sum + numbers[index]
  index += 1
end
puts sum
```

Comment: The normal way is `numbers.reduce(:+)`, but since you have to use `each`, I would suggest `numbers.each.reduce(:+) #=>  1315`.

Comment: I should elaborate. `numbers.reduce(:+)` produces the same result as `numbers.reduce { |total, n| total + n }`. See [Enumerable#reduce](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-reduce) (aka `inject`). It would be premature in your Ruby education to explain why this is true. For now, think of the former as a shorthand way of writing the later. `reduce`'s receiver can be an array (`numbers`) or an enumerator (`numbers.each`). Since the latter generates the elements of the former, either can be used. Try running `e = numbers.each` and `e.to_a` in IRB.

Answer (score 1):

There is. You don't need to track index manually when using `each`; you can simply do

```
numbers.each do |number|
  sum = sum + number
end
```